# Is there a way to use Xamarin Android Player with Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Tags: android, xamarin

On a mac.

I'm having an issue where neither Android Studio (completely up to date) or IntelliJ are seeing Xamarin Android Player when it is running.  Xamarin Studio sees it and deploys to it just fine.

I've searched and come up with nothing relating to using XAP with these 2 IDEs, so I'm not even sure if it works, although I would think they would see the player in the ADP.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Had to reinstall the XAP (delete with an app like App Cleaner), then updated Android Studio, then re-installed XAP, and now AS see it.